# Any non-whitespace regular expression

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Im trying to match a string agains a regular expression inside an if statement on bash. Code below:

```
var='big'
If [[ $var =~ ^b\S+[a-z]$ ]]; then 
echo $var
else 
echo 'none'
fi
```

Match should be a string that starts with 'b' followed by one or more non-whitespace character and ending on a letter a-z. I can match the start and end of the string but the \S is not working to match the non-whitespace characters. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `case $var in b[![:space:]]*[[:lower:]]) echo "$var";; esac`

Comment: @mikeserv,  that `*` would match a string containing a spacing characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - very good point. i overlooked +. thought it was just about the second char. its why i upvoted your answer.

Comment: `if` should not be capitalized

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are fully wright. `[:graph:]` is match all symbols from `\x21` to `\x7E`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In non-GNU systems what follows explain why `\S` fail:

The `\S` is part of a PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). It is not part of the [BRE (Basic Regular Expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01) or the [ERE (Extended Regular Expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01) used in shells.

The bash operator `=~` inside double bracket test `[[` use ERE.

The only characters with special meaning in ERE (as opposed to any normal character) are `.[\()*+?{|^$`. There are no `S` as special. You need to construct the regex from more basic elements:

```
regex='^b[^[:space:]]+[a-z]$'
```

Where the [bracket expression `[^[:space:]]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)  is the equivalent to the [`\S` PCRE expressions](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) :

The default `\s` characters are now HT (9), LF (10), VT (11), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32).

The test would be:

```
var='big'            regex='^b[^[:space:]]+[a-z]$'

[[ $var =~ $regex ]] && echo "$var" || echo 'none'
```

However, the code above will match `bißß` for example. As the range `[a-z]` will include other characters than `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` if the selected locale is (UNICODE).
To avoid such issue, use:

```
var='bißß'            regex='^b[^[:space:]]+[a-z]$'

( LC_ALL=C;
  [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; echo "$var" || echo 'none'
)
```

Please be aware that the code will match characters only in the list: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in the last character position, but still will match many other in the middle: e.g. `bég`.

---

Still, this use of `LC_ALL=C` will affect the other regex range: `[[:space:]]` will match spaces only of the C locale.

To solve all the issues, we need to keep each regex separate:

```
reg1=[[:space:]]   reg2='^b.*[a-z]$'           out=none

if                 [[ $var =~ $reg1 ]]  ; then out=none
elif   ( LC_ALL=C; [[ $var =~ $reg2 ]] ); then out="$var"
fi
printf '%6.8s\t|' "$out"
```

Which reads as:

- If the input (var) has no spaces (in the present locale) then
- check that it start with a `b` and ends in `a-z` (in the C locale).

Note that both tests are done on the positive ranges (as opposed to a "not"-range). The reason is that negating a couple of characters opens up a lot more possible matches. The UNICODE v8 has 120,737 characters already assigned. If a range negates 17 characters, then it is accepting 120720 other possible characters, which may include many non-printable control characters.

It should be a good idea to limit the character range that the middle characters could have (yes, those will not be spaces, but may be anything else).

Comment: what do the spaces do as ERE special characters?

Answer (score 6):

```
[[ $var =~ ^b[^[:space:]]+[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]$ ]]
```

What `[a-z]` matches depends on the locale and generally is *not* (only) one of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

`perl`'s `\S` (horizontal and vertical spaces) now also recognised by some other regexp engines is `[^[:space:]]` in POSIX and bash's EREs.

`bash` uses the system's regexp library to match those regular expressions, but even on systems (like recent GNU ones) where the regexps have a `\S` operator, that won't work because in:

```
[[ x = \S ]]
```

`bash` calls `regcomp("S")` and with:

```
[[ x = '\S' ]]
```

`bash` calls `regcomp("\\S")` (two backslashes).

However, with bash-3.1 or if you turn bash-3.1 compatibility on with `shopt -s compat31`, then:

```
[[ x = '\S' ]]
```

will work (will match a non-spacing character) on systems where EREs support `\S`.

```
$ bash -c "[[ x =~ '\S' ]]" || echo no
no
$ bash -O compat31 -c "[[ x =~ '\S' ]]" && echo yes
yes
```

Another option would be to put the regexp in a variable:

```
$ a='\S' bash -c '[[ x =~ $a ]]' && echo yes
yes
```

Again, that only works on systems that support that perl-like `\S` in their regexps.

The POSIX equivalent to that `bash`-specific code, would be:

```
if expr " $var" : \
        ' b[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]$' \
   > /dev/null; then
  printf '%s\n' "$var"
else
  echo none
fi
```

Or:

```
case $var in
  ([!b]* | *[!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz] | *[[:space:]]* | "" | ? | ??)
    echo none;;
  (*) printf '%s\n' "$var"
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

```bash
# match any non-whitespace char--works in bash and `grep` too
[^\r\n\t\f\v ]
```

### Details

Matching `\S` (any non-whitespace character) apparently doesn't work in regular expressions in `bash` or `grep` or similar. So, instead of using this to match one or more occurrences of any non-whitespace character:

```bash
# INSTEAD OF THESE (which do NOT work in bash or `grep`)

# match one or more non-whitespace chars
\S+
# or (same thing)
[\S]+
```

...use this:

### How to match all non-whitespace characters in `bash` and `grep`

```bash
# match one or more non-whitespace chars (DOES work in bash and `grep`!)
[^\r\n\t\f\v ]+
```

I learned this from https://regex101.com/. Click here: https://regex101.com/r/kM041K/1, and on the right-hand side of the screen, under the "EXPLANATION" section, you will see:

> `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

So, if in doubt about any regular expression, go to that website and see what it says.